# In WPF, how to know the object of binding source of a TextBlock using C# code?

Tags: wpf

I have defined a class `CLASS`, which contains 5 members: `int A`,  `int B`, `int C`, `string D`, `string E`. Also, I have binded `D` of an object `OB` of `CLASS` to a `TextBlock` in XAML using `ItemTemplate`.

Now I'm trying to get the object `OB` after clicking on the `TextBlock`, in order to do something with `OB.A`, `OB.B` etc.
Does anyone know how to do that in C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void myTextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var myTextBlock = sender as TextBlock;

    if (myTextBlock == null) return;

    BindingExpression binding = myTextBlock.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty);
    CLASS BindedInstance = binding.ResolvedSource as CLASS; // Equals to OB object

    BindedInstance.A = ... /// Do whatever you want with the rest of properties
}
```

Comment: Thx! I'm new in stackoverflow, so I am not familiar with the question regulation due to the current problem is in an emergency. Thx for the answer and editing the description of my question to make it more clear... :)

Comment: @XinkaiWang you are welcome. If my answer solved you problem please mark it as accepted (Click the vi sign on the left side of the answer)

Comment: By the way, what namespace is needed to use binding.ResolvedSource? My code doesn't get it right under ResolvedSource. VS tells me that System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression does not contain a definition for 'ResolvedSource'.

Comment: VS tells me that System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression does not contain a definition for 'ResolvedSource'. And it seems that my code missing a using directive or an assembly reference. How to solve the problem?

Comment: What VS are you using? What version of WPF?

Comment: You can use `binding.DataItem`

Comment: VS 2012 and SilverLight 5. binding.DataItem works!Thanks a lot :)